# How to setup mailcatcher and run as service in CentOS

Tags: centos, mailcatcher

I have followed the steps in this tutorial but it wouldn't work.

https://serversforhackers.com/setting-up-mailcatcher

I did however successfully installed mailcatcher and have tested. It is working, however I can't run it as a service.

Anyone knows how to do this in CentOS? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

All operations made by root or sudoer user.

1. create file /etc/init.d/mailcatcher
2. add to it this content (from https://gist.github.com/oppara/c4233b289c86e2b3cb66) :

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   # chkconfig: 345 99 1
   # description: mailcatcher
   # processname: mailcatcher

   start() {
       echo -n "starting mailcatcher:"
       /usr/local/rbenv/shims/mailcatcher --http-ip=0.0.0.0
       return 0
   }

   stop() {
       killall mailcatcher
       return 0
   }

   case "$1" in
       start)
           start
           ;;
       stop)
           stop
           ;;
       *)
           echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
           exit 2
   esac

   exit 0
   ```
3. make file executable:

   ```
   chmod +x /etc/init.d/mailcatcher
   ```
4. add service available:

   ```
   chkconfig --add mailcatcher
   ```
5. enable service:

   ```
   chkconfig mailcatcher on
   ```
6. start or stop service with this command:

   ```
   service mailcatcher stop|start
   ```

Comment: On CentOS7 I replaced killall with pkill and also change the path to "/usr/local/bin/mailcatcher".